# Android version dilemma

Tags: android

On calling back my first activity ,it should call onResume.It is calling the same in android version 2.2.But when I checked in for android 4.1 it is calling onCreate method that calls splashscreen and hence it looks like the app is restarting.How could I make sure that onResume is called for every version of android?

Thanks

Comment: Put here your onResume()

Comment: this isn't normal behaviour.. show the code where you are "calling back" to first activity

Comment: Are you calling the first activity after destroying it or are you going back?

Comment: returnIntent.putExtra("failString",checkBoxes.toString());
   LogCreator lg = new LogCreator();
  lg.writeBarcodeToFile("FS - "+checkBoxes.toString(),"" );
  setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
  finish();

Comment: Well in case the first activity somehow got stopped, for example lack of memory, the onCreate would be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henry said, you can't guarantee that onCreate won't get called again - you're not in charge of that lifecycle. If the system decides to get rid of your activity while it isn't in the foreground, then when you return to it it will be recreated. If you want to make sure that you don't show the splash screen again you will need to save state to say that it has been shown (e.g. using onSaveInstanceState). As an aside, splash screens generally aren't a great idea on android, partly for this reason. It's better to view your app as a loose collection of activities that can be entered and reentered somewhat randomly, as the android system basically does. Where you see splash screens used on android, it's common to see them slightly misbehave.

If you want to keep track of your application lifecycle, to which a splash screen might correspond, then you can subclass the Application object and put a flag there. However, android may leave your app running for weeks, so the user won't necessarily see that splash screen very often.

Keep in mind that the true purpose of a splash screen is supposed to be to show the user something nice while a long loading process is happening, and not to put your branding in their face. If you use the approach with onSaveInstanceState (and often onRetainNonConfigurationInstance too) then the cases where you show the splash screen would indeed be those where you need to redo that loading process, so that would be correct. However, it's generally better to rethink the design and bring up a minimal UI quickly, then show that some data is loading.

Finally, here's someone who goes into great depth on this subject: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632

Answer (score 1):

If the system has removed your activity while it was unused, it will receive an `onCreate` thats normal behavior.

You could make the splash screen part of a separate activity to avoid the problem.

Comment: But why would it???Its perfectly normal on my commando phone  i.e. having android 2.2

Comment: That depends on other circumstances, for example if a lot of other applications is running, available memory, ...

Comment: I dont think thats the possible reason.Anyways ,Thanks for your inputs..@Henry